# Use different variables for dev and prod with AngularJS and GruntJS

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am currently working on an Angular website that communicates with a RESTful API running on node.js that I built only for this app. They are two separate projects that runs on different ports.

While developing, I make the Angular app communicating with the local API. In production, the path to the API will be the IP address of the server. This is not a lot of work but I then need to change the address every time I want to deploy to production.

So here is some questions (sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find it) :

Is it possible to create a two-sided variable (in grunt, in angular) in order to use some address (localhost) for development and another address for production ?

Maybe I got it all wrong and I should merge the API with the app ? I would have one big web server running on the same port and I could use relative paths and get rid of hostnames. How can I do to merge the express routes for the API with the angular routes ?

Thank you !

Comment: This is the kind of thing you should read from a config and have different config files between dev and prod.  The code should always be the same between the environments, or you'll end up with unexpected prod bugs that don't repro in dev.

Comment: I agree Ryan, that's why I am looking for better solution.